# Animate blurred color blobs

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, html5-canvas, webgl, pixel-shader

What would be the most scalable and performance wise solution for **crossbrowsers**
to animate those blurred blobs in movement and changing color?(@example image)

Goal is to give calm ambient feel in color and movement animation.

One solution would be with transparent color-blob-dot images, but that comes
with clunky solution for color animate and scale department.

Directions?
Examples?
Advice?

anything would help

ty :)

[image: 123image]

Comment: Maybe you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177748/increasing-real-time-performance-on-canvas-effects/17178445#17178445) as a basis ? (there is a demo in there too)

Comment: Maybe check out http://glsl.heroku.com. Something like this? http://glsl.heroku.com/e#12090.0

Comment: Ty for the effort! This is exactly what I wished for(to be honest, already looked @ glsl.heroku.com) and had to decline beacause lack of crossbrowser support.

Comment: already found a solution for your question? Need something like this too.