# How can I achieve an animated marbled iridescent background effect?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Perhaps its best to start with an example.
http://decade.size.net/releases

This website shows the effect I am trying to create perfectly. I realise that canvas is being used; I'm just unsure how process-wise? The site is a little laggy most likely as there is a hell of a lot of stuff happening on the fly.

So I'm also wondering if its the best way to achieve this effect or if a looping video would be better?

Comment: The site works fine for me. Can't you find anything in their sources? Considering it's a canvas, it should be possible to obtain this information.

Comment: Looping a video is an option if you don't need the user to interact with the animation, but than you can consider an animated gif. If you do need the user to interact with the animation, consider using WebGL (some of the thing you can do with it): http://davidwalsh.name/webgl-demo

Comment: I've had a good hunt through the code; but its been minified and clearly theres parts to the puzzle i'm missing, I'm having a hard time finding any reference to the motion portion of the effect

Comment: The "minified code" problem you can solve with the beautifier: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: I've checked the code with jsbeautifier, it's not so much the format, just the sheer amount of stuff going on but thanks! I'm more looking for how this can be done rather than how it has been done in this instance, the decade site is just an example.

Comment: You might modify the concept of metablobs (metaballs) to get your effect. Epistemex did a good optimization of displaying metablobs with html canvas:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177748/increasing-real-time-performance-on-canvas-effects.  One problem you're going to face is that your effect will almost certainly involve `.getImageData` and `.putImageData` which are relatively slow--especially on mobile, because they are not GPU accelerated.  There are some good suggestions in the comments: use webgl image shaders and pre-create the effect and display it as a looping video.

Comment: Its a nice concept, I'm not sure it will be viable to create the same effect for me, but I'll definitely look into it!