# Animating Blobs using quadratic or bezier curves on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to work out a way to animate a series of circles that when they get close to each other, they melt into each other like blobs or liquid metal. Similar to the animation below.

I've searched for a few hours online for algorithms that might go part the way toward doing this, but the closest i've gotten is using blur functions to kind of fake it. I'm looking for a way to draw the objects entirely with curves.

[image: Blob Animation]

Comment: Try browsing for ["metaballs"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177748/increasing-real-time-performance-on-canvas-effects/17178445#17178445)

Comment: fantastic thanks - this goes a long way toward what I wanted - http://codepen.io/ge1doot/pen/RNdwQB